# Active Page Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am in planning stage for a browser add-on that I want to develop. The general idea is to have a timer that will record how long the user spends on each site (with a warning if you spend longer than X amount of time).

On page load isn't quite right- from my understanding this will record from the page load until it closes. If you have multiple tabs open it will be recording as "time spent" when you aren't actually viewing the site.

Q1. Please let me know if I am correct.

What I am ideally looking for is an "active document" event listener from a browsing session (HTML)
Q2. Is that possible and how would I do that.

Suggestions on alternative methods would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there is such thing like $(window).focus and .blur functions, you can count time with them:

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    //your code
});
$(window).blur(function() {
    //your code
});
```

time will be counted only when user is using your website, not only when its opened in one of his browser tabs.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have been exploring this and it seems like a rough solution. 

The application I am developing sits =as an addon to the browse primarily for productivity. Having to artificially apply focus and blur to every visited webpage seems a little inelegant. 

Though this and Page visibility API seem to be the only ways this can be done.

Comment: if you want more elegant solution you can do it in pure JS by window.onfocus and window.onblue - but implementation of jQuery functions that i post above is propably the same. Wish you luck!